# Make "socat" constantly listen for the magic packet

Tags: bash, socat

I have a RPi 1b+ v1.2 with Raspberry Pi OS June 2021.

I'm using `socat` to trigger a bash script that wakes another PC in the network up. I use this command:

```shell
sudo socat UDP-LISTEN:10 EXEC:scripts/pi-wol.sh,fork
```

but in throws an error

```
2021/09/05 19:26:38 socat[1743] E parseopts(): option "fork" not supported with this address type
```

It works fine without `fork` but only once and I need it to constantly listen. Any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you'd rather want:

```
socat -u udp-recvfrom:10,fork exec:scripts/pi-wol.sh
```

For upon every received UDP packet, fork a process to handle it and send the contents of the packet on the stdin of a new invocation of that script.

`-u` for unidirectional unless you want the output of the script to be sent back as UDP packets to the client.

Comment: That was all I needed. Thank you, Stéphane!